# Integrating lib to QML module

Tags: c++, cmake, qml, qtquick2

I am writing QML module, which uses lib (ex network) from my another project but i dont understand, how to link them. I'm getting undefined_reference error in mysocket.cpp file. I found a lot of references on how to integrate C++ code to QML module, but not lib. What am i doing wrong, how to link them correctly?

My project has that structure:

cppcomponents

- mysocket.h
- mysocket.cpp
- CMakeLists.txt

src

- main.cpp

CMakeLists.txt
Main.qml
qmlmodules

File's implementation
CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(AppExample VERSION 0.1 LANGUAGES CXX)
...
qt_standard_project_setup()
qt_add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    src/main.cpp
)

include (qmlmodules)
...
```

qmlmodules:

```
qt_add_qml_module(AppExample 
    URI "Main"
    VERSION 1.0
    NO_PLUGIN
    QML_FILES Main.qml
)
add_subdirectory(cppcomponents)
target_link_libraries(AppExample PRIVATE
    CppComponentsplugin
)
```

src/main.cpp:

```
...
Q_IMPORT_QML_PLUGIN(cppcomponentsPlugin)
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.loadFromModule("Main", "Main");
    return app.exec();
}
```

cppcomponents/CMakeLists.txt

```
# this is the way i add libs to another libs/executable
set(LIBS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../../../../libs")
add_subdirectory("${LIBS_DIR}/network" "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/network")
# and than i use target_link_directories(...)

qt_add_library(
    CppComponents
    # network   <- i tried to link it here
    STATIC
    # <- or here
)

qt_add_qml_module(CppComponents
    URI "cppcomponents"
    VERSION 1.0
    SOURCES
        mysocket.h
        mysocket.cpp
```

network lib CMakeFile.txt:

```
project(network LANGUAGES C)
...
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${NETWORK_LIBS})
...
```

Comment: didn't you try using `target_link_libraries` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @folibis.

It needs to use target_link_libraries insted of adding them in qt_add_library. I hope this helps to all beginners and saves their time.

```
qt_add_library(
    CppComponents
    STATIC
)

target_link_libraries(CppComponents PRIVATE
    network
)
```