Set QML_IMPORT_PATH environment variable from CMake
I'm writing an application that imports an external QML Module with Qt 6.5.3 and CMake.
The official Qt documentation says that QML engine searches for identified modules in the default paths: [...] Paths specified by the QML_IMPORT_PATH environment variable
If in my CMakeLists.txt I add set(ENV{QML_IMPORT_PATH} "path/to/my/module"), the engine fails to load it and function QQmlEngine::importPathList() doesn't include the newly added.
The only working solutions are:

calling the function QQmlEngine::addImportPath()
Setting in QtCreator Project -> Build Environment -> Use System Environment and
Set QML_IMPORT_PATH to path\to\my\module

I don't want to hardcode the path of my module in my source code or remember to edit the build environment variables.
Am I incorrectly setting the QML_IMPORT_PATH environment variable, or am I missing something?
Below, a minimal reproducible example:
// CMakeLists.txt
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(QmlApp LANGUAGES CXX)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

find_package(Qt6 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Quick)
qt_standard_project_setup(REQUIRES 6.5)

set(ENV{QML_IMPORT_PATH} "C:/Projects/QmlModules/SpecialModule")

qt_add_executable(qml-app
    main.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(qml-app
    PRIVATE Qt6::Core Qt6::Quick
)

// Main.cpp
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    qInfo() << engine.importPathList();
    // Prints only the current bin dir, two default Qt dirs and Qt install dir
    return 0;
}


Please include an [MRE] with your question. Additionally, in a common scenario, you wouldn't need addImportPath.

@smr edited with a minimal rep. example

I was primarily looking to see the SpecialModule part. However, if your module is using qt_add_qml_module and follows the > Qt 6.5 standards, then its prefix import path should be :/qt/qml/ (check here), which is also automatically registered in importPath. But, you still need to link that module using target_link_libraries, which is missing here. Also, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77274096/11603485.

kind a workaround, add some variable, for example add_definitions(-DMY_QML_IMPORT_PATH="C:/Projects/QmlModules/SpecialModule") and so in your c++ code: QQmlEngine::addImportPath(MY_QML_IMPORT_PATH)
